# Implementing an arithmetic expression in assembly

Tags: assembly, riscv

x13=((x2 ^ x3) + (x1 ^ x2) + x1)
Select below the RISC-V code snippet that implements the above expressions
I have to come up with a RISC-V code snippet that implements the above

I have come up with the following

```
xor x11,x2,x3
xor x12,x1,x2
add x14,x11,x12
add x13,x14,x1
```

Not sure if this is correct 
Need suggestions

Comment: Your solution looks correct.

Comment: It looks ok, though let's note that there are many other solutions, using different registers for the intermediate expressions, and, since all the operators are commutative, using different source operand orderings.  Further, since x13 is a target, we could use x13 itself as to hold one of the intermediate values, which would reduce register usage.